# Jscript regex to get text between slashes

Tags: regex, jscript

Trying to create regex to extract part of the string with use of jscript/jquery
I am noob in both :P

**String pattern**:

> A..Z/CB..C/ABC+BCD/ABCD/TextToGet1/TextToGet2/1-9/1-9

text to get is after 4th slash and 5th slash 
[TextToGet1] and 
[TextToGet2]

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `split` instead, since it is by `/` that you want your results like:

```
var result = " A..Z/CB..C/ABC+BCD/ABCD/TextToGet1/TextToGet2/1-9/1-9".split('/')
```

`result[4] //outputs TextToGet1`

and

`result[5] //outputs TextToGet2`

Comment: Simply didnt know this method. Thx for help

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:[^\/]*\/){4}([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)
```

The matches in group1 and group2

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/edXe6kVgHE)